# Object not being created after associated_model.create() call in rails 2.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have been stuck on a seemingly simple thing, but it's been two days and I can't figure out what I am missing, I am sure it's a small thing.

My system has `registrations` and a `registration` `has_many registration_transactions`.

A registration is first created as `incomplete` then there's a `checkout` and the registration is in `pending` state. In the `checkout` method, a `registration_transaction` is supposed to get created.

Both registration and registration_tranasction have a field `payment_method`, and if the payment_method is `Credit Card` and `transaction_type` is `payment` then another registration_transaction is created for the same registration where transaction_type is `Fee`

Here's the code that does all this:

```
if !self.valid?
    errors.add_to_base("Error encountered processing transaction: Invalid Registration Data Entered.")
  else
    #if self.registration_transactions.empty?
      registration_transactions.create(
        :transaction_type   => 'Fee',
        :payment_method_id  => self.payment_method_id,
        :amount             => event_registration_type_membership.price,
        :notes              => "#{event.code} - #{event_registration_type_membership.event_registration_type.name} Registration Fee",
        :ip_address         => self.ip_address,
        :status             => 'Processed',
        :date_1             => Date.current)
    #end


    if payment_method.name.eql? 'Credit Card'
      payment = registration_transactions.find_by_notes("#{event.code} - #{event_registration_type_membership.event_registration_type.name} Registration Fee Initial Payment")
      #Commented the line below and changed status to 'Processed'.
      #Client wanted to process a transaction automatically when a user registers for an event and pays through CC
      #payment = registration_transactions.build(:status => 'Draft') if payment.nil?
      payment = registration_transactions.build(:status => 'Processed') if payment.nil?



      payment.update_attributes(
        :transaction_type             => 'Payment',
        :payment_method_id            => self.payment_method_id,
        :amount                       => event_registration_type_membership.price,
        :notes                        => "#{event.code} - #{event_registration_type_membership.event_registration_type.name} Registration Fee Initial Payment",
        :credit_card_number           => self.credit_card_number,
        :credit_card_security_code    => self.credit_card_security_code,
        :ip_address                   => self.ip_address,
        #:status                      => 'Draft', changed status to processed
        :status                       => 'Processed',

        :credit_card_type_id          => self.credit_card_type_id,
        :credit_card_expiration_date  => self.credit_card_expiration_date,
        :billing_city                 => self.transaction.billing_city,
        :billing_state                => self.transaction.billing_state,
        :billing_postal_code          => self.transaction.billing_postal_code,
        :billing_country              => self.transaction.billing_country,
        :billing_first_name           => self.billing_first_name,
        :billing_last_name            => self.billing_last_name,
        :billing_address_1            => self.transaction.billing_address_1,
        :date_1                       => Date.current)

      result = payment.process(self.ip_address,false)
      logger.info "GCS - attempted to process payment via authorize.net, RESULT=" + result.to_s
      logger.info "GCS - messages from authorize net=" + payment.errors.full_messages.to_s


      logger.info "GCS - result: #{result.inspect}"
      logger.info "GCS - payment: #{payment.inspect}"
      logger.info "GCS - payment.errors: #{payment.errors.full_messages}"
      self.save!

      errors.add_to_base(payment.errors.full_messages) if !result



    else #check payment
      result = true
    end
  end
```

The problem is that when I put checkpoint and check in runtime then `registration_transactions` has two transactions, one for Fee and another for payment, just like desired. But when the registrations completes and I look at the database, there's only the payment transaction. Somehow the Fee transaction doesn't get saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line does not save the build associated model until it is saved.

```
registration_transactions.build(:status => 'Processed')
```

Then,

```
payment.update_attributes(...)
```

which updates an existing record in DB. You'd need to build your associated record with all the attributes and then save.